# Need help understanding Math in C++

Tags: c++, math

Hey guys I am doing an extra credit program and I get it to run but every input i use it always ends up to be 1. Can anyone point me into the right direction on where i messed up please and thank you

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#define Euler 2.718282
#define Pi 3.141593

int main(void)
{
    int n;
    int n_fact(int n);

    printf("Enter n: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &n);

    while (n < 0)
    {
        printf("The n value must not be negative");

        printf("Enter the value of n: ");
        scanf_s("%d", &n);
    }
    printf("n! Stirling approximation value about %i is %i ", n, n_fact(n));

    getchar();
    getchar();
    return 0;


}


int n_fact(int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return (int)(1 + 1 / (12 * Euler) + 1 / (288 * n*n) - 139 / (51840 * n*n*n));
    }
}
```

Comment: Your formula is wrong. This will always evaluate to 1.0306 plus/minus something small -> truncation will yield 1.

Comment: @PaulR so i would need to change int n_fact(int n) to float n_fact (int n)?

Answer (score 2):

You are having problems here because of integer arithmetic, particularly integer division:

```
return (int)(1 + 1 / (12 * Euler) + 1 / (288 * n*n) - 139 / (51840 * n*n*n));
```

You have also missed out an important part of [the formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation#An_alternative_derivation), so even with floating point division the above expression will still not return the correct value.

Look at the series again:

[image]

In order to evaluate this you're going to need to (a) use floating point throughout and (b) you'll need to include the `sqrt(2 * pi * n) * pow(n / e, n)` term too. You can omit all but the first few terms of the series, though, depending on required accuracy (apparently your assignment only requires that you use the first four terms).

Comment: @BaummitAugen: you're right - OP has missed out a whole chunk of the formula.

Comment: @PaulR the given formula we have to use is [1 + 1/(12*n) + 1/(288*n^2)-139/(51840*n^3)] so only thing i did was instead of using pow did n*n ect

Comment: You need the `sqrt(2 * pi * n) * pow(n / e, n)` term too, otherwise you'll get some very small numbers.

Comment: @Failingengineer I guess you misunderstood your prof then, the leading factor is essential if you want to approximate `n!`. Right know, you approximate the error of the Stirling Formula.